# Launch a new page in Zend/php on button click

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

PHP & Zend Noob here

I've downloaded the skeleton project from here: `https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication`

Say i want to open a new page that simply displays **"hello world"** text if click on the "ZF2 Development Portal" button(bottom left green button) on the page that launches --- how do i do this? See image:
[image]

I've read through this tutorial, but i'm not sure how the model, view, or controller are actually launched? See tutorial: `http://blog.wilgucki.pl/2012/07/tworzenie-modulw-w-zend-framework-2.html`

From looking at the code, i know that i will have to change this line of code:

```
<div class="span4">
        <h2><?php echo $this->translate('Follow Development') ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo sprintf($this->translate('Zend Framework 2 is under active development. If you are interested in following the development of ZF2, there is a special ZF2 portal on the official Zend Framework website which provides links to the ZF2 %swiki%s, %sdev blog%s, %sissue tracker%s, and much more. This is a great resource for staying up to date with the latest developments!'), '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Home">', '</a>', '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2/blog">', '</a>', '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2">', '</a>') ?></p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->translate('ZF2 Development Portal') ?> &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
```

More specifically this line:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-success" href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->translate('ZF2 Development Portal') ?> &raquo;</a></p>
```

but i'm really confused as to what i'm supposed to change it to in order to launch a new page. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn how ZF2 works first.

Create a controller in a controller folder ( PageController.php )
inside create a controller class
and create a method as the doc says.

```
function HelloAction(){
return "Hello world";
}
```

create a link that navigates to /page/hello/

and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question like "Oh, i heard cars are qool, how to i build a car?"

Please refer to the [official Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html) and get familiar with what the QuickStart is providing you. If you do not understand that at all, then learn about Model - View - Controller separately. Because it's no use trying to build a car without knowing the mechanical background ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this will work for you:
Inside application/controller create IndexController.php

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

       //$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layout');
    }

}
```

Then Inside application/views/scripts create index/index.phtml

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: is this the phtml file: $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layout');? also ... where do we call indexcontroller then? and how?